# How to change style attribute of element with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, attributes, use-state, use-ref

Hello I have seen tutorials but not sure how to change element attributes in React like with a button click change the width of an element. This is easy with vanilla javascript using document.querySelector. But how is it done in React?? State? or useRef? It says to avoid refs too much so is there a useState way to do this? Toggling the width is my goal, but any advice is appreciated. I don't think I am supposed to use document.querySelector...

My Attempt:

```
const myRef = useRef("80%");
  const changeWidth = () => {
    widthRef.style.width = "100px";
  };
```

```
<div>
  <div style ={{width:400px, height: 400px}} ref ={myRef}>
  <button onClick={changeWidth}></button>
</div
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change style directly using style prop

```
//
const [width, setWidth] = useState("400px")

function hanldeWidthChange() {
   // you can set width to any value you want
   setWidth("100px")
}

<div>
  <div style ={{width: width, height: "400px"}}>
      <button onClick={() => hanldeWidthChange()} ></button>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: works great thank you, I added an if statement for the toggle part. the handle is spelled wrong btw typo maybe!